# Data quality rule on REDCap returns two associated discrepancies

Tags: redcap, data-quality

REDCap returns two associated discrepancies to the same rule.
One shows that the values involver have no complete data ([no_data]) an the second one returns the case with the discrepancy that matches the rule. I am only interested in the second discrepancy, as the field have a data and also on my rule I am asking to only have return the case with completed values, as I am comparing different fields.

**Rule:**

```
[form_1_complete] <> '' and [impl_range] <> '' and [impl_exact] <> '' and [form_1_complete] = '2' and [impl_range] = '0' and [impl_exact] >'2.7'
```

**First discrepancy (same record ID):**

"Diameter range (mm)"
impl_range: [no data]
"Exact diameter (mm)"
impl_exact: [no data]
"Complete?"
Form_1_complete: [no data]

**Second discrepancy (same record ID):**

"Diameter range (mm)"
impl_range: 0
"Exact diameter (mm)"
impl_exact: 3.6
"Complete?"
Form_1_complete: 2

REDCap version: 13.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps putting quotes around the 2.7 in [impl_exact] >'2.7' is causing the problem, as 2.7 is a numeric value. It may also be worth trying to use double quotes. Try one or both of these proposed solutions, and let me know if they don't work. I can help troubleshoot further.

```
  [form_1_complete] <> '' and [impl_range] <> '' and [impl_exact] <> '' and [form_1_complete] = '2' and [impl_range] = '0' and [impl_exact] > 2.7
```

OR

```
      [form_1_complete] <> "" and [impl_range] <> "" and [impl_exact] <> "" and [form_1_complete] = '2' and [impl_range] = '0' and [impl_exact] > 2.7
```